# expandableListView inside menu (drawer)

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I wanted to insert expandableListView inside sidebar menu after I generated the listview I tried to insert it inside the expandableListView instance but it says nullpointer here are some parts of the code

**the end of Activity_main_drawer file**

```
<ExpandableListView
    android:id="@+id/expandablelisto"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"/>
```

**Main activity**

```
ListView modeList = new ListView(this);
    String[] stringArray = new String[] { "Bright Mode", "Normal Mode" };
    ArrayAdapter<String> modeAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, stringArray);
    modeList.setAdapter(modeAdapter);
    //here the problem
    ExpandableListView expandableListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.expandablelisto);
    expandableListView.addView(modeList);
    //end
```

**the error**

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use `SimpleExpandableListAdapter` for `ExpandableListView` for example:

```
   SimpleExpandableListAdapter adapter = new SimpleExpandableListAdapter(
                this,
                groupData,
                android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1,
                groupFrom,
                groupTo,
                childData,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                childFrom,
                childTo);

           ExpandableListView  expandableListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.expandablelisto);
            expandableListView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: thank you, but the problem is that the class can't find the view it says null pointer when I put the ExpandableList inside activity_main.xml it says nothing but once I insert it inside drawer.xml it can't find it

Comment: @j-dope `findViewById()` returns a View if it exists in the layout you provided in setContentView(), otherwise it returns null and that's what happening to you.

Example if you `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);` and then call `findViewById(R.id.first_View);` it will return a `View` which is your layout.

But if you call `findViewById(R.id.second_View)`; it will return null since there is not a view in your `activity_first.xml` layout called `@+id/second_View`.

Comment: @j-dope and check context in your drawer.xml

Comment: I understand can you just help me how can I get the view it says null 
I cal findviewbyid in mainactivity I can get drawer view and also menuitems but when I try to get the view of expandablelistview it says null